# AngularJS redirect $location.path('examp.html')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

Im struggeling with a redirect function, When im calling the function there is infornt of the main domainpath a /#!/ 
http://domain.de/backend/#!/splitscreen.html

```
var app = angular.module('loginApp', []);
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
$scope.email = "exampel@adress.de";
$scope.password = "password";

        $scope.login = function () {
            $location.path();
            if($scope.email === "exampel@adress.de" || $scope.password === "pw"){
                console.log($location.path('splitscreen.html'))
                $location.path('splitscreen.html');
            }else{
                $scope.alertMsg = "Wrong Email or Password"

            }

        };

});
```

Comment: What URL do you expect to get? This is how angularJS does it routeing (although I'm fairly sure this change has been reverted), it's called a [hashbang/shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) fyi

Comment: I expect to get domain.de/backend/splitscreen.html , Sry im new to programming and i dont understand the problem what you mentioned to be honest...